# why simplexml_load_file() can not use some xml rss?

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am using simplexml_load_file() in a function an it works with every rss successful
But i have a problem with Rss of [this site](http://www.bignewsnetwork.com)
for example:

http://www.bignewsnetwork.com/index.php/nav/rss/4a6d634cbccbbfe2

I cannot get this page source using file_get_contents() too;

There are my Errors:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://www.bignewsnetwork.com/index.php/nav/rss/4a6d634cbccbbfe2) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in C:\wamp\www\php\44\xml.php on line 5

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://www.bignewsnetwork.com/index.php/nav/rss/4a6d634cbccbbfe2" in C:\wamp\www\php\44\xml.php on line 5
bool(false)
```

How can i use this RSS?
please help me.

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` You dont have permission to access that resource.

Comment: First warning kind of says it: server issued a 403 Forbidden response.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I said in my comment:

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden You dont have permission to access that resource.

However I can hit it from a browser so it may be something to do with a user agent (or some other HTTP header its trying to validate). In that case you can use `curl` to pull the data and supply whatever user agent (or other necessary header) you like.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.bignewsnetwork.com/index.php/nav/rss/4a6d634cbccbbfe2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Identify the rquest User Agent as Chrome - any real browser, or perhaps any value may work
// depending on the resource you are trying to hit
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36');


$feed = curl_exec($ch);
$rss = new SimpleXMLElement($feed);
```

Comment: You are very very kind. I love you.